# AttributeError occurs in datetime expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

While following Python tutorials, I came to know about the built-in `repr()` function, which according to the official documentation:

> Returns a **string** containing a printable representation of an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

To sum up, for many object types including most built-ins, `eval(repr(obj)) == obj` (or the equivalent  `obj == eval(repr(obj))` returns **True**, also mentioned in the above documentation.

But, while executing the following code, `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'` occurs in the last statement i.e. `print(today == eval(repr(today))`.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = 'Hello, Pythoneers'
print(s == eval(repr(s)))  # no errors here

today = datetime.now()
print(today == eval(repr(today))) # error occurs here
```

Can someone explain the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: `datetime` uses `datetime.datetime(...)` in the representation. The name `datetime` *in your example* doesn't reference the module but the class inside the module. Use `import datetime` instead, then use `today = datetime.datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` uses `datetime.datetime(...)` in the representation:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 27, 16, 46, 59, 491342)
```

That's the *module name*, followed by the class name, which is an attribute of the module:

```
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/.../lib/python3.6/datetime.py'>
>>> datetime.datetime
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

The name `datetime` *in your example* doesn't reference the module but the class inside the module:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime  # the form used in your question
>>> datetime
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Use `import datetime` instead, then use `today = datetime.datetime.now()`.

`repr()` calls the [`object.__repr__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which is not passed any information on how your code is referencing the class; so the instance can't adjust what string it generates. Even if more information was available, you wouldn't want to generate different strings *anyway*; do you really want to figure out what `fluzborx.datetime()` is when someone jokingly used `import datetime as fluzborx` somewhere?

Note that the goal of `repr()` is to *aid debugging*, not to provide full serialisation support of data types. If you want to serialise `datetime` instances, use a proper serialisation format such as [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), or write your own datetime -> string and string -> datetime conversions (e.g. for JSON, perhaps use ISO8601 string conversions).